# Java javac is not regonized as an internal or external command

Tags: java

I was just starting to learn basic java for I apparently need it to be able to code bukkit plugins for minecraft and I'm stuck on the following issue.

I have made the HelloWorldApp.java in the folder c/test but it wont do want its supposed to do. Any help would be good and please try to dumb down any coding, etc

This is how I invoked it:

```
C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop>cd C:\test

C:\test>javac HelloWorldApp.java
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\test>
```

Comment: Is JDK in jour path? You can check if you open 'cmd' and execute path command.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup Java in path.

**Windows XP:**

1. Select Start, select Control Panel. double click System, and select the Advanced tab.
2. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
3. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

**Windows Vista:**

1. From the desktop, right click the My Computer icon.
2. Choose Properties from the context menu.
3. Click the Advanced tab (Advanced system settings link in Vista).
4. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
5. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

**Windows 7:**

1. From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
2. Choose Properties from the context menu.
3. Click the Advanced system settings link.
4. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
5. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: i tried that. i put in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin; as a environment variable

Comment: @ozm8ey A JRE has no compiler. [Download a JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) instead.

Comment: still happening this time: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;

Comment: @ozm8ey Is the "PATH" variable correct? Have you tried to reboot your pc?

Comment: thanks you so much, it works now. It was driving me crazy lol